# Website login automation without XHR request

Tags: authentication, automation

Background: I'm trying to automate local ISP login using simple request in python (without selenium, that's last resort as I'm trying to learn other ways too).

Upon inspecting website, submit button calls the `validateForm()` function.

```
function validateForm(){
    var input=true;
    var uname = "?"+document.login.Username.value+"+/@";
    var pwd = "?"+document.login.Password.value+"+/@";      
    document.login.LoginName.value=encodeURIComponent(uname); 
    document.login.LoginPassword.value=encodeURIComponent(pwd);
    if (input==true&&document.login.checker.checked) 
        toMem(this);
}

function toMem(a) {
    newCookie('theName', document.login.Username.value);     // add a new cookie as shown at left for every
    newCookie('theEmail', document.login.Password.value);   // field you wish to have the script remember
}

function newCookie(Username,value,days) {
     var days = 30;   // the number at the left reflects the number of days for the cookie to last
                     // modify it according to your needs
     if (days) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
       var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString(); }
       else var expires = "";
       document.cookie = Username+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; 
}
```

No where it is sending any request.

The website doesn't make any XHR request. I'm not able to grasp how they are making the login work. I found one request from 'other' tab of network (chrome dev tools). From where it is generating this request!!!

```
   fetch("http://ip:port/Sristi3/SRISTI/loginUI.do2", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
  },
  "referrer": "http://ip:port/Sristi3/SRISTI/Login.jsp?",
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": "Username=username&Password=password&LoginName=encodedusername&LoginPassword=encodedpass",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

I tried to simply paste the request in console but this also does not make the login. Returned a `promise` with `[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"` and `[[PromiseValue]]: TypeError: Failed to fetch, message: "Failed to fetch", stack: "TypeError: Failed to fetch"`. What and where to look for? Any help?

Comment: fetch call is made instead of XHR request. In body section you can see the username and password is being passed using the names used in corresponding UI elements. If you just paste this as is then how the credentials will be passed, hence it wont work.

Comment: Of course, I changed username, encodedusername etc...

Comment: it says encodedpass...did you also pass it as encoded ? whats the question here ? How can we make login auth without XHR ? Please have a read - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I simply copied "as fetch" (can be copied as cURL etc) from the network request (thus all IP, port, id, pass, encoded part taken care) and run it in console (after logging out).

Comment: It seems the site is doing multiple redirects... :(